# RecyclerView Pagination and ViewPager sharing data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, pagination, android-viewpager, paging

I want to implement pagination for my recyclerview which fetches data from Firebase Realtime Database.

On each item click, I want to open another activity which contains a viewpager and display the same data with the recyclerview.

How can I do that? Can someone show me a proper way to solve this problem? Thank you!